# SAS macro error

Tags: debugging, macros, sas

I submit the following program

`%let col1 = dept;
 %let data = company;
 proc sql;
 select *
 from &data, employee
 where &data.&col1 = employee.name;
 quit;`

And I get this error:

`ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: companydept.`

What caused such error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first period after the macro variable is used as a macro delimiter. You need to add another period like this.

&data..&col1 =

Comment: why we need delimiter in this scenario?

Comment: You need one full stop for the where statement - e.g. 'company.dept' - and one to 'finish' the name of the macro variable.  SAS uses a few delimiters - [space] being the most common one - to determine the end of a macro variable's name.

Comment: So is it equivalent to write `&data. &col1 =`? I remember in some cases we can omit the delimiters. But I forgot the details.

Comment: @zhuoer - it isn't equivalent because SAS will keep the space in that instance.  SAS requires a delimiter when the ending of the macro variable name is ambiguous.  A period is the chosen delimiter for a user to explicitly tell SAS where the end of the macro name is.  The period, like the ampersand, are replaced with the macro variable.  So if you ever have an instance where you need a period right after a macro variable, you have to use two periods.  One to mark the end of the variable, and the other to specify the character 'period'.